# Compare number of users on year ago

Tags: sql

I want to get the count of distinct current users and one year ago using sql I have used the following query but it gets the current number and zero for one year ago values.

```
   select CAST(root_tstamp as DATE) as Date,
   count(DISTINCT userid) as sign_ups,
   count(Distinct case when CAST(root_tstamp as DATE) = ADD_MONTHS(CAST(root_tstamp as 
    DATE),-12) then userid end) as Last_year_Signups
   FROM table1
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided the dB schema.

Comment: @FortyTwo, Just a single table with all the columns in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `sql server` code.

For other type of DBs if there are any difference in syntax it will be only in date_add function.

```
;with table1 as(select '2022-01-25 13:14:37.840' as root_tstamp,1 as userid
union select '2022-01-25 13:14:37.840' as root_tstamp,2 as userid
union select '2021-01-25 13:14:37.840' as root_tstamp,1 as userid
union select '2021-01-25 13:14:37.840' as root_tstamp,2 as userid
union select '2022-01-25 13:14:37.840' as root_tstamp,1 as userid

)
select CAST(A.root_tstamp as DATE)as date
 ,count(DISTINCT a.userid) as sign_ups
 ,count(Distinct dateadd(MONTH,-12,CAST(B.root_tstamp as DATE))) as Last_year_Signups
from table1 a
left join table1 b on a.userid = b.userid and CAST(A.root_tstamp as DATE) = dateadd(MONTH,12, CAST(B.root_tstamp as DATE))
```

> **Result**

| date | sign_ups | Last_year_Signups |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-25 | 2 | 0 |
| 2022-01-25 | 2 | 1 |