# Getting the number of users for this year and last year in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My table is like this:

| root_tstamp | userId |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.725+00:00 | d2212 |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.669+00:00 | ad323 |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.629+00:00 | adfae |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.573+00:00 | adfa3 |
| 2022-01-26T00:13:24.552+00:00 | adfef |
| ... | ... |
| 2021-01-26T00:12:24.725+00:00 | d2212 |
| 2021-01-26T00:15:24.669+00:00 | daddfe |
| 2021-01-26T00:14:24.629+00:00 | adfda |
| 2021-01-26T00:12:24.573+00:00 | 466eff |
| 2021-01-26T00:12:24.552+00:00 | adfafe |

I want to get the number of users in the current year and in previous year like below using SQL.

```
Date             Users    previous_year
2022-01-01        10           5
2022-01-02        20           15
```

The code is written as follows.

```
select CAST(root_tstamp as DATE) as Date,
   count(DISTINCT userid) as users,
   count(Distinct case when CAST(root_tstamp as DATE) = dateadd(MONTH,-12,CAST(root_tstamp as DATE)) then userid end) as previous_year
FROM table1
```

But it returns 0 for previous_year values.
How can I fix that?

Comment: Please share the complete data with the previous year too. If possible share the insert scripts.

Comment: @AmitVerma I just added the previous data structure too. I don't have the insert scripts and I new to the SQL. Thank you for help

Comment: This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70849185/compare-number-of-users-on-year-ago/70849625#70849625) already, please refer

Comment: If you want the number of unique users for the current year, why does your query starts with 'Date' (not year), and your 'I want' shows a date, not a year?

Comment: Is it mysql or SQL Server? AS your query syntax belongs to SQL Server and you have tagged mysql

Comment: @userMT results should be for this year dates, not year wise.

Comment: @AmitVerma this sql use in Holistic BI platform, I'm not sure what SQL they use

Comment: So it is each day this year, and same day last year?

Comment: @userMT, yes it should be each day this year and same day last year.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for SQL Server:

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT 2022 [year]
              UNION ALL
              SELECT 2021 )
SELECT cte.[year],
       COUNT(DISTINCT test.userId) current_users_amount,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN YEAR(test.root_tstamp) < cte.[year]
                           THEN test.userId
                           END) previous_users_amount
FROM test
JOIN cte ON YEAR(test.root_tstamp) <= cte.[year]
GROUP BY cte.[year]
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=88b78aad9acd965bdbac4c85a0b81927

Comment: I want to see it by Date not aggregated to year

Answer (score 0):

This query (for MySql) returns unique number of userids where the root_timestamp is in the current year, by day, and the number of unique userids for the same day last year. If there is no record for a day in the current year nothing will be displayed for that day. If there are rows for the current year, but no rows for the same day last year, then NULL will be shown for that lastyear column.

```
SELECT cast(ty.root_tstamp as date) as Dte,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ty.userId) as users_this_day,
       count(distinct lysd.userid) as users_sameday_lastyear
FROM test ty
     left join
     test lysd
     on  cast(lysd.root_tstamp as date)=date_add(cast(ty.root_tstamp as date), interval -1 year)
WHERE YEAR(ty.root_tstamp) = year(current_date())
GROUP BY Dte
```

If you wish to show output rows for calendar days even if there are no rows in current year and/or last year, then you also need a calendar table to be introduced (let's hope that it is not what you need)